# organizing images by resolution with batch files

Tags: windows, command-line, images, batch

Doing some digging I'm trying to figure out a command line solution for organizing very large archives of images based on their resolution into folders, 1920x1080, 1600x1200, 1600x900, etc.

I've come across a few post on Superuser mentioning something called ImageMagick, is that the best method to the madness I'm trying to accomplish? I've never used any command line functions/applets/tools other then those that come from Microsoft.

I'm rather new to command line usage but ive been enjoying the hell out of it using Powershell, xcopy and robocopy.

I am slowly trying to push myself further into the Linux world with Ubuntu running on one of my physical machines as well as a virtual machine so that's an option as well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You started out asking something about organizing images based on resolution and then you went off on a tangent about command line languages...

Comment: I was trying to get at where my experience level with command-line is as well as state what platforms I use. I figured It would help give a perspective of where I sit knowledge wise.

Comment: Understood, but it would be better to have a little background on your actual problem as well. As this sits, I have no idea what it is you're specifically asking help with.

Comment: Specifically I have a very large archive of images, I would like to organize these images into folders using command line based on there resolution 1920x1080, 1600x1200, 1600x900, etc. It'd be nice if I could add a tag associated to there resolution.

Comment: You should probably add that into the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Imagemagick is the way to go. You will need to read the documentation, because it's a very powerful package, but I'll help get you started. The `identify` command is what you are looking for. Again, look at the docs, but these options will print the file name and resolution on an image (`%f` prints the file name, `%w` and `%h` print the width & height in pixels):

```
identify -format "%f %wx%h" SampleImage.png
```

Output: `SampleImage.png 1024x1024`

If you had a folder full of jpeg images, then you could generate a file with the image name and resolutions of all jpegs with this command (on Windows):

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do identify -format "%f %wx%h\n" "%i" >> resolutions.txt
```

The `\n` is added to force a newline between image names, else everything ends up on one line.

That's just the start. The method you use to group and move them will also be an interesting problem.

**Edit:** One option you could use to organize the file is to add the resolution to the name. The `identify -format` can be used to build a batch file to rename the images:

```
 for %i in (*.jpg) do identify -format "ren ""%f"" ""%wx%h-%f""\n" "%i" >> renImages.cmd
```

The resulting file content will look like this:

```
ren "Sample Image.jpg" "1024x1024-Sample Image.jpg"
ren "Sample2.jpg" "1024x512-Sample2.jpg"
...
```

Run the `renImages.cmd` at the prompt to rename all the images, and then you can just sort and group the images however you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll start looking in that direction. So dose Imagemagick function as a separate software suite where I run a different executable, or is it like xcopy or robocopy where from the standard cmd window i just type the application before my command? Thanks For your Help

Comment: Imagemagick is run from the command line. The installer should put an entry in your PATH variable so that you can run it without referencing a full path to the .exe. It comes with about 18 different programs that perform image manipulation of some sort - resizing, compositing, adding frames, etc. By using these commands in conjunction with the host OS shell language, you can batch process large amounts of images.